# How to build kubernetes cluster On-premise

Tags: kubernetes

I install kubernetes on my machine which has arm CPU now. I want to build kubernetes cluster.
I want to know how to do that, are there any github codes for reference? I would be happy if it includes ansible.

Kubernetes version:1.24.2
Cloud being used: On-Premise
Installation method: ansible
Host OS: Ubuntu18.04(arm(aarch64))
CRI and version: Docker 20.10.17

Comment: You only want to create `kubernetes cluster`?

Comment: check this URL https://landscape.cncf.io/card-mode?category=certified-kubernetes-installer&grouping=category and search for "**Platform - Certified Kubernetes - Installer**", you will find all the certified installer list, since you have mentioned about ansible, `kubespray` seems about right.

Answer (score 0):

For your question `if it includes ansible`

[Kubespray](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubespray/) is ansible way of creating kubernetes cluster

For your question `CRI and version: Docker 20.10.17`

From kubernetes 1.24.x onwards the dockershim has been removed.  You can use [cri-dockerd](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/migrate-dockershim-dockerd/) through which you can use docker.  Also you can use other [CRI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) as well